# How many predicates are allowed in a WHERE clause?

Tags: google-bigquery

We are dynamically building a SQL statement in which the WHERE clause will consist of multiple predicates joined together using OR

```
SELECT cols 
FROM t
WHERE (t.id = id1 AND t.PARTITIONDATE = “yyyy-mm-dd”) 
   OR (t.id = id2 AND t.PARTITIONDATE = “yyyy-mm-dd”) 
   OR (t.id = id3 AND t.PARTITIONDATE = “yyyy-mm-dd”) 
   OR (t.id = id4 AND t.PARTITIONDATE = “yyyy-mm-dd”)
   etc…
```

What is the maximum number of conditions that BigQuery allows in such a SQL statement?

I’ve looked at the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#where_clause) but the answer is not there.

Comment: Those are two factors for you to consider: 
**Maximum unresolved Standard SQL query length** - 1 MB - `An unresolved Standard SQL query can be up to 1 MB long. If your query is longer, you receive the following error: The query is too large. To stay within this limit, consider replacing large arrays or lists with query parameters.` and **Maximum resolved legacy and Standard SQL query length** - 12 MB - `The limit on resolved query length includes the length of all views and wildcard tables referenced by the query.`

Comment: Ok, 1MB seems very generous, should be no problem there. I’d be surprised (pleasantly so) if there wasn’t a limit on number of predicates in a WHERE clause though, I’ve worked with other database platforms that did have such restrictions.

Comment: you can easily experiment with it - i just did very quick and simplified experiment and was able to use 50K predicates joined together with OR

Comment: Excellent. If you reply as an answer I’ll mark it as such. Do you have a script that you used to generate that statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are two factors for you to consider:

- Maximum unresolved Standard SQL query length - 1 MB - An unresolved Standard SQL query can be up to 1 MB long. If your query is longer, you receive the following error: The query is too large. To stay within this limit, consider replacing large arrays or lists with query parameters.

and

- Maximum resolved legacy and Standard SQL query length - 12 MB - The limit on resolved query length includes the length of all views and wildcard tables referenced by the query.

You can easily experiment with how many predicates you can use - for example - i just did very quick and simplified experiment and was able to use 50K predicates joined together with OR using below super simplified and totally dummy script

```
execute immediate (
  select 'select 1 from (select 1) where ' || string_agg('1 = ' || num, ' or ')
  from unnest(generate_array(1,50000)) num
)
```